# How to check if ReflectionProperty is accessible?

Tags: php, reflection

Is there a way to check that I've already set a ReflectionProperty to be accessible?

```php
class Foo {
    private   $baz  = 'bar';
}

$foo = new Foo();

$prop = new ReflectionProperty($foo, 'baz');
$prop->setAccessible(true);
```

Doing `$prop->isPrivate();` will return `true` before and after setting the accessibility (as expected). Is there a way to tell that I've already set the accessibility to true?

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php#reflectionproperty.constants.is-public) doesn't show anything like an `$accessible` property in the ReflectionProperty class, so I'm not sure how it's making it accessible, unless it's done on the `Foo` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method inside try-catch block:

```
ReflectionProperty::getValue
```

> Throws a ReflectionException if the property is inaccessible. You can
>   make a protected or private property accessible using
>   ReflectionProperty::setAccessible().

Documentation Link:
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php

Code:

```
function isPropertyAccessible($property){
     $result = true;
     try{
        ReflectionProperty::getValue($property);
    }
    catch(ReflectionException $e){
       $result = false;
    }
       return $result;
    }
```

Comment: I realize it's possible to figure out. I guess I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of checking. It just doesn't make sense to me that they would allow us to set the accessibility, but not check it, and then throw an exception if we didn't do it.

Comment: @GreeKatrina  May I know why do you need to check the accessibility. Seems you are working on some interesting project. May I know if its some open source project? Could you please upvote my answer.